# Low Traffic on Established Website, Steps to Gain Traffic, Remove Penalties?

Tags: seo, google, traffic

My kid made this joke website a few years ago. I helped him with hiding the joke answer.

Google hates it. 2,832 views a month, $4 of adsense, 16 clicks.

The site has 1850 jokes, one per page. 1 view per joke, per day would be 30 x 1850 or 55,500 views a month. Not 2,832 views.

I'd like to get him 10 views per joke per day per month. 555,000 views a month.

I'm dealing with a VCD malware infection on there here this weekend. There seems to be scripts in the database. I though I had everything cleaned out. I'm pretty sure that's the pop up ads.

A few years ago he left form to post automatic and spam posts were made. I cleaned that all up but there may be penalties?

What can I do to help him out and get his half million views a month with his 1850 jokes?

A few suggestions and steps to get us started would be appreciated!

Comment: It isn't necessarily that Google hates it, it may be ranking very well but not many people search for the jokes.    I wouldn't expect people to search for a joke they already know.  If they don't know the joke, they wouldn't know what to search for.

Comment: Related: [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google)